# Reading text from a file and use in a formula

Tags: c, file-io

I just want to ask this. I have some kind of a file in .txt format, and the content looks like this:

```
GRAMtoTONN 0.000001
GRAMtoNWTN 0.009807
GRAMtoPOUN 0.002205
GRAMtoCRAT 5
GRAMtoOUNC 0.03527
TONNtoGRAM 1000000
TONNtoNWTN 9807
TONNtoPOUN 2205
TONNtoCRAT 5000000
TONNtoOUNC 35270
NWTNtoGRAM 102
NWTNtoTONN 0.000102
NWTNtoPOUN 0.2248
NWTNtoCRAT 509.9
NWTNtoOUNC 3.597
POUNtoGRAM 453.6
POUNtoTONN 0.0004536
POUNtoNWTN 4.448
POUNtoCRAT 2268
POUNtoOUNC 16
OUNCtoGRAM 28.35
OUNCtoTONN 0.00002835
OUNCtoNWTN 0.278
OUNCtoPOUN 0.0625
OUNCtoCRAT 141.7

LEGEND:
GRAM = Grams
TONN = Tonnes
NWTN = Newton (in Earth's surface)
POUN = Pounds
OUNC = Ounces
CRAT = Carat
```

Now I want to put, let's say I need `GRAMttoTONN`'s value, into an equation to put in my source code. I have no idea how to use fscanf in this kind of text file. Can you help me out? All I know was to open the file and that's it. Thanks for your time :))

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtok()`

You have to read the file line by line (`fgets()`) and then run `strtok()` on each line to get your values.

Suppose you previously opened the file, and `fp` is a pointer to it.
And `pch` is just a pointer to char.

```
int i;
while(fgets(line, 90, fp) != NULL)
{
    i = 0;
    pch = strtok(line, " \n"); // there is a 'space' before '\n'
    while(pch != NULL)
    {
        if(i==0)
             printf("Text : %s\n", pch);
        else if(i==1)
             printf("Number : %lf\n", atof(pch));

        pch = strtok(NULL, " \n"); // here too
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Reading text from a file and use in a formula***
In addition to `strtok()`, there are a couple of additional functions to consider:  `strstr()` and `strtod()`.

First, in your code, reproduce the information you know is in your input file as an emum, a char array and a double array:

```
enum {
    GRAMtoTONN,
    GRAMtoNWTN,
    GRAMtoPOUN,
    GRAMtoCRAT,
    GRAMtoOUNC,
    TONNtoGRAM,
    TONNtoNWTN,
    TONNtoPOUN,
    TONNtoCRAT,
    TONNtoOUNC,
    NWTNtoGRAM,
    NWTNtoTONN,
    NWTNtoPOUN,
    NWTNtoCRAT,
    NWTNtoOUNC,
    POUNtoGRAM,
    POUNtoTONN,
    POUNtoNWTN,
    POUNtoCRAT,
    POUNtoOUNC,
    OUNCtoGRAM,
    OUNCtoTONN,
    OUNCtoNWTN,
    OUNCtoPOUN,
    OUNCtoCRAT,
    MAX_CONV
};  


char sConv[][11] = 
    {
    "GRAMtoTONN",
    "GRAMtoNWTN",
    "GRAMtoPOUN",
    "GRAMtoCRAT",
    "GRAMtoOUNC",
    "TONNtoGRAM",
    "TONNtoNWTN",
    "TONNtoPOUN",
    "TONNtoCRAT",
    "TONNtoOUNC",
    "NWTNtoGRAM",
    "NWTNtoTONN",
    "NWTNtoPOUN",
    "NWTNtoCRAT",
    "NWTNtoOUNC",
    "POUNtoGRAM",
    "POUNtoTONN",
    "POUNtoNWTN",
    "POUNtoCRAT",
    "POUNtoOUNC",
    "OUNCtoGRAM",
    "OUNCtoTONN",
    "OUNCtoNWTN",
    "OUNCtoPOUN",
    "OUNCtoCRAT",
   };

double dConv[MAX_CONV];
```

***Now, you can populate*** a *conversion* variable, dConv, with values you can use in your formulas using the following example code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *buf = {0};
    char *junk = {0};
    int i;
    char line[80];
    char sString[80];
    double x;
    double Grams;

    FILE *fp = {0};
    fp = fopen(".\\in.txt", "r");// in.txt includes only first 25 lines 
                                 // shown in your example 
    if(fp)
    {
        while(fgets(line, 80, fp))
        {
            for(i=0;i<MAX_CONV;i++)
            {
                if(strstr(line, sConv[i]))
                {
                    //Use this...
                /// buf = strtok(line, " \n");
                /// buf = strtok(NULL, " \n");
                /// dConv[i] = strtod(buf, &junk);
                    //OR this...  (preferable IMO)
                    sscanf(line, "%s %lf",sString, &dConv[i]); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //example conversions: NWTN to Grams
    Grams = 10.00 * dConv[NWTNtoGRAM];  // 1020 grams


    return 0;
}
```

The results of your example input file, and this code populates dConv as shown:

[image]